# Laravel 8 - "npm run dev" not working. sh: 1: mix: Permission denied

Tags: laravel

I have virtual machine on Vagrant.
Mount my folder on vagrant:
[Vagrant config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNInl.png)

I wanted to create a new Laravel project (jetstream livewire).
The following commands are executed correctly.

1. sudo composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravelAndroid
2. add schema to database
3. edit .env => connect to mysql
4. cd laravelAndroid
5. sudo composer require laravel/jetstream
6. php artisan jetstream:install livewire

After step #6 I get the following message: "Please execute "npm install && npm run dev" to build your assets."

I run "npm run dev" and console return:
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYwPo.png)

I do not know what access is involved. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH2Ls.png)

When i change "mix" to "asset" in guest.blade.php- everything is ok.
[change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ2aw.png)

Comment: try changing the owner of the shared folder to www-data in your config

Comment: Did you run `npm install` ?

Comment: @SarwarAhmed of course. N69S - I have changed. It did not bring a positive result

Comment: I confirm the issue in Vagrant with Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 4):

Delete and reinstall

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```